# stopword removal in C++ code

Tags: c++

*can Anyone help me make the stopword to be removed..I could not.. still appear after       run!*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char filename[50];    //open file
ifstream example;
cin.getline(filename , 50);
example.open(filename);
if(!example.is_open())
{
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
char word[50];
example>>word;
while (example.good()&&word!="a"&& word!="an"&&word!="be"&& word!="at"&&  word!="the")
{
cout <<word<<" "; // remove stopwords
example>>word;

}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

*can Anyone help me make the stopword to be removed..I could not.. still appear after       run!*

Comment: What is "the stopword"? Rather than just pasting code here, can you tell us what you're trying to do, and what you're currently seeing, ie a clear description? We're not psychic :)

Comment: `word != "a"` You're comparing pointer values. Use `std::string` instead of a char array and... profit.

Comment: Why not use `std::string`? Not only will it make your comparisons work as expected, it will also prevent hideous bugs if an input word is longer than you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare C-strings with the `==` operator. The easiest solution to your problem will be to use `std::string`:

```
string word;
example >> word;
while (example.good() && word != "a" && word != "an" && word != "be" && word != "at" && word != "the")
{
    cout << word << " "; // remove stopwords
    example >> word;
}
```

On the other hand, this will actually not remove all, as you call it, stopwords. It will just print all words until the first “stopword” is read, and then the whole loop will stop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using C-style strings, which are fiddly to use correctly. The simplest option is to use the C++ strings library:

```
#include <string>

std::string word;
```

and the rest of your program should work as expected. This will also prevent the hideous stack-corruption bug that your program will experience if an input word is too long.

If you really want to muck around with character arrays for educational purposes, then you'll need to use the C strings library to compare them:

```
#include <cstring>

if (std::strcmp(word, "a") != 0 && ...)
```

Your code compares the address of the array containing the input word with the address of a string literal; these will never be equal.

Comment: Thanks alto i use this way for my code :)

Answer (score 1):

When removing [stopwords](http://www.textfixer.com/resources/common-english-words.txt), remove not only a few of them.

In addition, you should apply the Porter algorithm to your piece of code.

The [Porter Stemmer](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/c_thread_safe.txt) has to be applied regarding string similarity if you wanna check a filtered text.

Yes, it is in C, but only applying a few words (like your question) is not an adequate removal procedure of stopwords. The C code gives you an impression if you really wanna stem in addition to removal of stopwords. This depends on the purpose.

Have done both in 2008 to filter many text fragments. Both was relevant.

hth

Answer (score 0):

A competent compiler with warnings turned on will fix your problem for you.  Here's what mine said:

```
warning: result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified (use strncmp instead)
      [-Wstring-compare]
    while (example.good()&&word!="a"&& word!="an"&&word!="be"&& word!="at"&&  word!="the")
                               ^ ~~~
```